# How to spilt the currency and the value into different coumns

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with stock data:

```
stock,value
stock1,$30
stock2,£31
stock3,$50
```

How can I spilt the column value in order to have two columns currency and value.
An example of output:

```
stock,currency,value
stock1,$,30
stock2,£,31
stock3,$,50
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
library(data.table)#v1.9.5+
setDT(df1)[, c('currency', 'value') :=tstrsplit(value,
             '(?<=[^0-9])', perl=TRUE, type.convert=TRUE)]
df1
#    stock value currency
#1: stock1    30        $
#2: stock2    31        £
#3: stock3    50        $
```

Or

```
library(tidyr)
extract(df1, value, into=c('currency', 'value'), '([^0-9]+)(.*)')
#    stock currency value
#1 stock1        $    30
#2 stock2        £    31
#3 stock3        $    50
```

Or using `base R`

```
cbind(df1[1],read.table(text=sub('(?<=[^0-9])', ' ', df1$value, 
                perl=TRUE), col.names=c('currency', 'value')))
#    stock currency value
#1 stock1        $    30
#2 stock2        £    31
#3 stock3        $    50
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(stock = c("stock1", "stock2", "stock3"), 
value = c("$30", 
"£31", "$50")), .Names = c("stock", "value"), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Comment: Very nice and elegant!

Answer (score 2):

Akrun beat me to it, but here's yet another:

```
require(stringr)
str_match(c('$30', '£500'), '^([$£])([0-9\\.]+)' )[,2:3]
     [,1] [,2] 
[1,] "$"  "30" 
[2,] "£"  "500"
```

You can flesh out the rest.

Answer (score 0):

Using `sqldf`:

```
sqldf("SELECT stock, 
      SUBSTR(value, 1, 1) As currency, 
      SUBSTR(value, 2, LENGTH(value)) AS value 
      FROM df1")
```

or

```
sqldf("SELECT stock, 
      rtrim(value,'0123456789') AS currency,
      ltrim(value,'$£') AS value
      FROM df1")
```

Output:

```
   stock currency value
1 stock1        $    30
2 stock2        £    31
3 stock3        $    50
```